# Tokens to Words mapping in the tokenizer decode step huggingface?

Tags: pytorch, tokenize, huggingface-transformers

Is there a way to know the mapping from the tokens back to the original words in the `tokenizer.decode()` function?
For example:

```py
from transformers.tokenization_roberta import RobertaTokenizer

tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained('roberta-large', do_lower_case=True)

str = "This is a tokenization example"
tokenized = tokenizer.tokenize(str) 
## ['this', 'Ġis', 'Ġa', 'Ġtoken', 'ization', 'Ġexample']

encoded = tokenizer.encode_plus(str) 
## encoded['input_ids']=[0, 42, 16, 10, 19233, 1938, 1246, 2]

decoded = tokenizer.decode(encoded['input_ids']) 
## '<s> this is a tokenization example</s>'
```

And the objective is to have a function that maps each token in the `decode` process to the correct input word, for here it will be:
`desired_output = [[1],[2],[3],[4,5],[6]]`
 As `this` corresponds to id `42`, while `token` and `ization` corresponds to ids `[19244,1938]` which are at indexes `4,5` of the `input_ids` array.

Comment: Can you please added how you have created the tokenizer object and which imports did you use (probably a BERT based tokenizer)?

Comment: Added the full example, thanks for that!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use the fast tokenizers, i.e. the rust backed versions from the `tokenizers` library the encoding contains a `word_ids` method that can be used to map sub-words back to their original word. What constitutes a `word` vs a `subword` depends on the tokenizer, a word is something generated by the pre-tokenization stage, i.e. split by whitespace, a subword is generated by the actual model (`BPE` or `Unigram` for example).

The code below should work in general, even if the pre-tokenization performs additional splitting. For example I created my own custom step that splits based on PascalCase - the `words` here are `Pascal` and `Case`, the accepted answer wont work in this case since it assumes words are whitespace delimited.

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('roberta-large', do_lower_case=True)

example = "This is a tokenization example"

encoded = tokenizer(example)

desired_output = []
for word_id in encoded.word_ids():
    if word_id is not None:
        start, end = encoded.word_to_tokens(word_id)
        if start == end - 1:
            tokens = [start]
        else:
            tokens = [start, end-1]
        if len(desired_output) == 0 or desired_output[-1] != tokens:
            desired_output.append(tokens)
desired_output
```

Answer (score 15):

**transformers version>=2.9.0:**

The FastTokenizers return a [BatchEnconding](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/main_classes/tokenizer#transformers.BatchEncoding) object that you can utilize:

```py
from transformers import RobertaTokenizerFast

tokenizer = RobertaTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('roberta-large')

example = "This is a tokenization example"

enc = tokenizer(example, add_special_tokens=False)

desired_output = []

#BatchEncoding.word_ids returns a list mapping words to tokens
for w_idx in set(enc.word_ids()):
    #BatchEncoding.word_to_tokens tells us which and how many tokens are used for the specific word
    start, end = enc.word_to_tokens(w_idx)
    # we add +1 because you wanted to start with 1 and not with 0
    start+=1
    end+=1
    desired_output.append(list(range(start,end)))
```

Output:

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4, 5], [6]]
```

**transformers version<2.9.0:**

As far as I know, there is no built-in method for that, but you can create one by yourself:

```py
from transformers.tokenization_roberta import RobertaTokenizer

tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained('roberta-large', do_lower_case=True)

example = "This is a tokenization example"

print({x : tokenizer.encode(x, add_special_tokens=False, add_prefix_space=True) for x in example.split()})
```

Output:

```
{'This': [42], 'is': [16], 'a': [10], 'tokenization': [19233, 1938], 'example': [1246]}
```

To get exactly your desired output, you have to work with a list comprehension:

```py
#start index because the number of special tokens is fixed for each model (but be aware of single sentence input and pairwise sentence input)
idx = 1

enc =[tokenizer.encode(x, add_special_tokens=False, add_prefix_space=True) for x in example.split()]

desired_output = []

for token in enc:
    tokenoutput = []
    for ids in token:
      tokenoutput.append(idx)
      idx +=1
    desired_output.append(tokenoutput)

print(desired_output)
```

Output:

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4, 5], [6]]
```

Comment: Thanks. I need the indexes of the relevant encoded tokens, after adding the special tokens, as later on I'm averaging the feature outputs of the model on those idxs(you can see that our example outputs are different )

Comment: Nether the less, if no such default function exists, it's pretty straightforward, I'll write it and post it here, thanks 

Comment: It's a workaround, as it ignores other special tokens, like <sep> etc. But the general Idea is clear, thanks:)